# How to define a function to return an array of an enum's values, using the child type (the enum implements an interface)?

Tags: java, types, enums, casting

I have a pool of many configuration settings, and each configuration setting has a pool of configuration options. Ideally, I want to be able to set a setting by using something like sendConfiguration(ID, OPTION).

Here is the Configuration class. It is an enum that maps the ID of the configuration to the set of options that are available for that configuration. For now, we'll just assume we have a configuration for the brightness setting.

```
public enum Configuration {

    BRIGHTNESS(166, BrightnessConfigOptions.values());

    private int configurationID;
    private ConfigOption[] configOptions;

    Configuration(int configurationID, ConfigOption[] configOptions) {
        this.configurationID = configurationID;
        this.configOptions = configOptions;
    }

    public int getConfigurationID() { return configurationID; }
    public ConfigOption[] getConfigOptions() { return configOptions; }
}
```

BrightnessConfigOptions looks like the following:

```
public enum BrightnessConfigOptions implements ConfigOption {
    DARK(1),
    NORMAL(2),
    BRIGHT(3),
    VERY_BRIGHT(4);

    private int configValue;

    BrightnessConfigOptions(int configValue) {
        this.configValue = configValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int getConfigValue() { return configValue; }
}
```

And the ConfigOption interface looks like this:

```
public interface ConfigOption {
    int getConfigValue();
}
```

So, as an example, the desired usage would be:

```
sendConfiguration(Configuration.BRIGHTNESS, Configuration.BRIGHTNESS.getConfigOptions().DARK)
...
void sendConfiguration(Configuration configuration, ConfigOption configOption) {
    System.out.println(configuration.getConfigurationID());
    System.out.println(configOption.getConfigValue());
}
```

This code does not work nicely because `getConfigOptions` returns `ConfigOption[]` and therefore I do not know the type, so I cannot write `.DARK` without casting first.

Either my design is wrong here, or I am forgetting something syntactically that would make this much easier. How can I make the typing work elegantly here?

Comment: I don't see a problem with casting, as long as you know what to cast it to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example this would appear to do what you asked.

I also recommend you look into both [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) and [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) as they may provide additional alternatives.

```
interface ConfigOption {
   int getConfigValue();
}
enum BrightnessConfigOptions implements ConfigOption {
   DARK(1), NORMAL(2), BRIGHT(3), VERY_BRIGHT(4);

   private int configValue;

   BrightnessConfigOptions(int configValue) {
      this.configValue = configValue;
   }

   public int getConfigValue() {
      return configValue;
   }
}

enum ColorConfigOptions implements ConfigOption {
    RED(10), BLUE(20), GREEN(30);

   private int configValue;

   ColorConfigOptions(int id) {
      this.configValue = id;
   }
   public int getConfigValue() {
      return configValue;
   }
}

enum Configuration {

   BRIGHTNESS(166), COLOR(167);

   private int configurationID;

   private Configuration(int id) {
      this.configurationID = id;
   }
   public int getConfigurationID() {
      return configurationID;
   }

}

public class EnumMapDemo {


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new EnumMapDemo().start();
   }
   public void start() {

      sendConfiguration(Configuration.BRIGHTNESS, BrightnessConfigOptions.DARK);
      sendConfiguration(Configuration.BRIGHTNESS, BrightnessConfigOptions.BRIGHT);
      sendConfiguration(Configuration.COLOR, ColorConfigOptions.RED);

   }

   void sendConfiguration(Configuration configuration,
         ConfigOption c) {
      System.out.println(configuration.getConfigurationID());
      System.out.println(c.getConfigValue());
   }
}
```